# Android background service with no UI is not answering

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I try to create a background service with no user interface and I created it with `BroadcastReceiver` and added my necessary things in the manifest file. Then I configure [Nothing](https://www.programmersought.com/article/5560819605/) as written in the link. I'm testing on an Android emulator, when I execute my app nothing happen and the service is not starting. Where is my problem?

Here is my manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.myapplication22">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication22">
    
        <service android:name=".MyService" />
    
    
        <receiver
            android:name=".StartReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my BroadcastReceiver

```
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    Log.i("MYSERVICE","override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent)")
    if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED ) {
        Intent(context, MyService::class.java).also {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startService(it)

                return
            }
            context.startService(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Service

```
class MyService : Service() {
    
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        if (intent != null) {
            println("MYSERVICE STARTED AUTOMATICALLY")
        }
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        println("MYSERVICE override fun onCreate() {")

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        println("MYSERVICE override fun onDestroy() {")

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your targetSDK set at? How are you testing  (OS version/emulator/device make and model)?

Comment: your `Service` will start only when `BOOT_COMPLETED` action will be received, so only when app installed and system restarts. it won't start when you just install app through adb (as you configure to start Nothing when installed)

Comment: @snachmsm so what you suggest

Comment: @MorrisonChang         minSdkVersion 23, targetSdkVersion 30 Emulator Pixel 2API R

Comment: @saulyasar posted answer with some suggestion, check it out

Answer (score 3):

your `Service` will start only when `BOOT_COMPLETED` action will be received, so only when app already installed and system restarts. it won't start when you just install app through adb (as you configure to start Nothing when installed)

make some `Activity` [fully transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-activity-on-android) with `startService` in `onCreate` and just after that `finish()` call. include `<activity` declaration in manifest, but without any `<intent-filter`. then instead of Nothing to run when app install just pick Specified Activity and point on this transparent one, which starts `Service` and quits after that. without `intent-filter` `Activity` won't be visible in launcher and only way to start it will be your configuration in AS

when you will be sending your app to end-users then remove `<activity` declaration leaving no actual way to run this transparent `Activity`. only `Service` can be started then, in current circumstances only when system boots up

btw. your [Nothing](https://www.programmersought.com/article/5560819605/) link assumes your app will be system-belong, moved to system partition/folder. do you have such privileges? (on usual user device this won't be possible, you need root privileges) without that all red-marked lines in `<application` tag won't work

edit:

step 1:

create file `res/values/styles.xml` and past below or if present already add below `<style` tag

```
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

step 2: create new `Activity` and declare in manifest with above style

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"/>
```

if you add below `<intent-filter` to `<activity` tag then this `Activity` shows in system UI (launcher), so just don't do that, placing here just to inform

```
// launcher icon declaration, not for OPs case
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    // MAIN must be placed with first LAUNCHER declaration
</intent-filter>
```

note that you can also create multiple `<activity` tags with `LAUNCHER` declaration (second and further without `MAIN` tag), making your app show multiple icons, one per `Activity` `LAUNCHER`-declared (you can also change their names and icons as far as I remember)

step 3: inside `onCreate` just after `super.onCreate` call start your `Service` and then quit this invisible `Activity`

```
startService(this, MyService.class); // will start service
finish(); // quits activity
```

step 4: under `Edit Configurations...` instead of Nothing just pick `Specified Activity`

Comment: But the idea is here when i create activity i also need to create app instead of app i want to create Service will work on background and without ui ,is it possible what you write?

Comment: can you write also example from my example? because looks like so complicated

Comment: you are creating an app, just look on manifest structure, there is `<application` tag, which contains `Service` declaration (background worker). `Activity` is intended to have layout and shows on foreground, just add one (without declaring it to be shown in OS UI) just for testing puproses. when you install such app from APK file nothing will run (besides your on `BOOT_COMPLETED` `Service`) and nothing shows in launcher. only Android Studio declaration/running procedure is starting this `Activity`, which shouldn't be visible, start `Service` and quits. edited my ans, check it out

Comment: btw. about APK installing - when someone install your app not-through-AndroidStudio (from apk or from some store, e.g. Play Store) also nothing happens, nothing will run. your current code is starting only on `BOOT_COMPLETED`, so device must be restarted after app installation. if this is your intended behavior then I don't see nothing wrong in declaring additional `Activity` just for `Edit Configurations...` option and easier development